# click element html, Show type html tags to text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Show type html tags to text, with **click** element html

**Before :**

```
<div id="test">
  <p>
    Lorem <b>ipsum</b>
  </p>
</div>
<span id="show_type">This ....</span>
```

**After :**

```
<div id="test">
  <p>
    Lorem <b>ipsum</b>
  </p>
</div>
<span id="show_type">This div p b</span>
```

Comment: This may be helpful https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/tagName

Comment: Hi welcome to SO I close this as duplicate, first try something and then ask an specific question if you get stuck at some point